# How build JS files in esm format

Tags: javascript, browser, bundle, bundler, es6-modules

I have `/src` folder with JS, CSS (maybe LESS/SASS) files with ReactJS application in esm format. I need keep esm format with multiple files (I don't want to bundle all files in single file).

```
/src
  index.js
  app.js
  style.less
/dist
  index.js
  app.js
  style.css
```

In simple case, esm working in browsers out of the box, but in common case we need:

1. Import libraries from node_modules (browsers don't have it out of the box)
2. Do something with importing stylesheets, maybe add CSS modules support